# session in a property field

Tags: asp.net

Is it ok to get/set session variable inside a private/public property?

```
private List<FileAttachment> fileAttachments;
public List<FileAttachment> FileAttachments
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["key"] != null)
        {
            fileAttachments = (List<FileAttachment>)Session["key"];
        }
        return fileAttachments;
    }
    set
    {
        fileAttachments = value;
        Session["key"] = fileAttachments;
    }
}
```

The goal here is I'd like for the container class (of this user control the property is in) to be able to set the `List<T>` depending on what entity and show existing attachments that's stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not very safe; `List<T>` is not thread-safe.

You can never modify the list after assigning it to the property, since some other request thread might be reading it.

Therefore, you should make it a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` rather than `List<T>`.
(and make sure your `FileAttachment` class is immutable or thread-safe)

---

Other than that, it depends where the property is.
If it's on a control or page, it's fine.

Comment: So does that mean if it's in a user control the container class cannot set the ReadOnlyCollection<T>? On different note, seems like it would be better not to have session part of the property.

Comment: Can you or anyone help me understand or visualize a use case where a problem could arise if not done properly

Comment: @rod: If you get two requests in the same session at once, they will both modify the same objects at once.  If the objects are not thread-safe, the will get messed up.